# How to Iterate over node.js module object to find all the Properties and Methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to list down all the Properties and Methods which belong to `os` Node.js module. One alternative is:

```
var os = require('os');
Object.keys(os);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(os);
```

Since the `os` module is an Object, I should be able to iterate over it like any other object to list down all it's Properties and Methods. But the following code throws error. Please let me know What I am missing here?

```
for (let i in os) {
    console.log(i + ':'+ os[i])
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: You can iterate over it, you just can't always `console.log()` its values.

Comment: I wonder why?  I tried making an object with few properties and methods and I was able to iterate over it to get the Key/Value pairs.

Comment: My best guess is that the `os` module contains things written in C, not javascript. And those bits of C are not implemented in a way so that they have a representation that can be sent to the console.

Answer (score 3):

`os.constants` is an object with a `null` prototype. Since it therefore has no `toString` method on it, there is no way to convert it to a primitive string value.

```js
const o = Object.create(null);

console.log('toString', o.toString);
console.log(o + '');
```

Since `console.log` is a bit smarter than just using `toString`, you can use it directly:

```
Object.keys(os).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key, os[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` is forcing node to convert the object values into strings:

```
console.log(i + ':'+ os[i])
```

You could try without concatenation:

```
console.log(i, os[i])
```

So you dont coerce your obj into string, but I think [`console.dir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options) is a good method to get the info you are trying to see.

```
const os = require('os');
console.dir(os);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for.